# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll when using MLApp in c#

Tags: c#, matlab

I'm trying to use the following code of matlab in c#:

```
function [B] = AutoCorrelation()
img = imread('F:\\2dAutocorrelationFunction\\New_folder\\1.bmp');
img2 = rgb2gray(img);
[n m]=size(img2);
B=abs(fftshift(ifft2(fft2(img2).*conj(fft2(img2)))))./(n*m);
```

and the c# code is:

```
MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();
matlab.Execute(@"cd 'F:\2dAutocorrelationFunction\New_folder'");
object result = null;
matlab.Feval("AutoCorrelation", 1, out result);
object[] res = result as object[];
```

But, when I execute the code, my program throws the following exception on matlab.Feval();

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

can someone tell me what the wrong I did? and how to fix it?

Comment: Change your function to use: img = imread('F:\2dAutocorrelationFunction\New_folder\1.bmp'); ... the other thing....is your code running inside a webservice/website within IIS? It could be that you don't have access rights to that path.

Comment: Also look at the "InnerException" it might give you more error information

Comment: I changed my function to the function you wrote, but it didn't worked yet. and I don't use webservice or website, I use windows forms applications. and InnerException shows no further information